# Finding a function with given area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

I need to find the function $g(x)$. The curve extends from $(10, 10)$ to $(30, 10)$. The area under the curve to the $x$-axis and between $x = 10$ and $x = 30$ must equal to exactly $200$, i.e. $$\int_{10}^{30} g(x) dx = 200$$ The stipulation is that the curve must be as short as possible and be 'smooth'.

I'm at a loss where to begin. I have gathered that the arc length formulae $$L=\int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+[f′(x)]^2} dx$$ needs to be used but I don't get how to apply it.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

What about the constant function $g(x) = 10$ ?